# System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu has a problem with merging elements

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a menu in C# which is not a menu strip but instead a `System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu`, a professional menu in C#, but it has a problem.

This MainMenu is in parent window, and when we open child windows in parent by clicking on menu, an icon on the left side appears, and the number of icons appear. If number of menus are clicked and their child forms opened, that completely disturbs the menu. Secondly when child forms open, cross and minimize icons also get together.

You can find the image attached to understand clearly what I mean. The image attached is when I clicked on 4 menus and 4 child forms opened in a parent form. Remember I open the form without deleting the previous instance, because I don't want the child which is opened should be cleared when re-opened.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in Winforms.  Do *not* create the MDI child window in the constructor, do it in a Load event handler you write.

Comment: can you explain more, i did not get you!

Comment: You need to explain what was unclear about it, "constructor" and "Load event" are very common Winforms programming terms.  Did you write the code for this program?

Comment: on menu click, i write forexample BlahForm f = new BlahForm;  f.MdiParent=this; f.show();

Comment: The very first one is important, not the ones you create later.

Comment: you mean, f.MdiParent should not be written, i should place it in BlahForm load constructor?

Comment: No.  When you start the program, is there already a child window without you using the menu?  That one.

Comment: @HansPassant let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2637/discussion-between-muhammad-atif-agha-and-hans-passant)